# Linux pppd fails but NetworkManager works

Tags: ubuntu, networking, modem, point-to-point-protocol

So I'm trying to get my PtP modem "Telit ME910" connected to the Verizon LTE network via pppd using Ubuntu 16.04.

If I hook it up and go through the standard Network Manager steps of "Enable Mobile Broadband", it will find the default APN and list it, so I can then select "Verizon 4G LTE Contract 1" and it connects beautifully. It created the ppp0 interface with an IP, and I can then PING 8.8.8.8 successfully.

If I hook it up and go issue "pppd call verizon", it will create the ppp0 interface with an IP, but PING fails? I know ModemManager & NetworkManager are doing more that pppd is, but I can't trace out what I'm missing. Any assistance would be amazing.

**/etc/ppp/peers/verizon:**

```
/dev/ttyUSB1
115200
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/ppp/peers/verizon-chat"
noauth
#nodefaultroute

defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
usepeerdns

local
debug
persist

#updetach
nodetach
```

**The Details of the working connection:**

```
# ip route show table all
default dev ppp0  proto static  scope link  metric 700 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ppp0  scope link  metric 1000 
local 100.124.161.186 dev ppp0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 100.124.161.186 
broadcast 100.124.161.186 dev ppp0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 100.124.161.186 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0  pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eno1  table local  metric 256 linkdown  pref medium
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101 pref medium

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:100.113.251.242  P-t-P:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:82504 (82.5 KB)  TX bytes:62112 (62.1 KB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     700    0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ppp0
```

Syslog here: [workingSyslog](https://pastebin.com/j8xYZYTe)

**Details of the failed connection:**

```
# ip route show table all
default dev ppp0  scope link 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 100.122.108.86 
local 100.122.108.86 dev ppp0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 100.122.108.86 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0  pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eno1  table local  metric 256 linkdown  pref medium
unreachable default dev lo  table unspec  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101 pref medium

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:100.122.108.86  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:38 (38.0 B)  TX bytes:2065 (2.0 KB)

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

Syslog here: [failedSyslog](https://pastebin.com/04BRwBYQ)

Any hints or advice are greatly appreciated. I have gone as far as manually altering the routing tables and interface settings for ppp0 so they match exactly what I see when I use the GUI(NetworkManager) but it still refuses to allow even a simple PING 8.8.8.8 to get through on ppp0. ***So clearly there are some networking details that aren't reflected by the standard "ifconfig/route -env/ ip route show table all" type commands that are causing the disconnect.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after searching long and hard, I finally added "+ipv6" to my ppp options file, and everything started working. Now to figure out and understand why that option is required!

Answer (score 1):

With NetworkManager the `ppp` Connection Configuration is not stored with the common Network Configuration Scripts.
To debug the `ppp` Connection I used the `nmcli` Command in the System Console.
To do so I would start with the Listings of

```
$ nmcli con show
$ mmcli dev status
$ ip route
```

On a working Gateway Server with working `ppp` it looks like this:

```
$ nmcli con show
NOMBRE  UUID                                  TIPO            DISPOSITIVO 
ppp0    ec723ebc-3675-4d8a-81e8-8989bb275307  pppoe           enp1s0      
enp1s0  c0ab6b8c-0eac-a1b4-1c47-efe4b2d1191f  802-3-ethernet  --          
$ nmcli dev status
DISPOSITIVO  TIPO      ESTADO         CONEXIÓN 
enp1s0       ethernet  conectado      ppp0     
lo           loopback  sin gestión    --       
$ ip route
default via 80.58.67.182 dev ppp0 proto static metric 100 
80.58.67.182 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src <net.wor.k.ip> metric 100
```

Then run `$ nmcli con show ppp0`

It might give you something like this:

```
$ nmcli con show ppp0
connection.id:                          ppp0
connection.uuid:                        ec723ebc-3675-4d8a-81e8-8989bb275307
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.interface-name:              enp1s0
connection.type:                        pppoe
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        100
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (predeterminado)
connection.timestamp:                   1529677563
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (predeterminado)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     desconocido
connection.lldp:                        -1 (default)
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          no
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             --
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:   --
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:        --
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:            --
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             1 (default)
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       (predeterminado)
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (predeterminado)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       (predeterminado)
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (desconocido)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     eui64
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
ppp.noauth:                             yes
ppp.refuse-eap:                         no
ppp.refuse-pap:                         no
ppp.refuse-chap:                        no
ppp.refuse-mschap:                      no
ppp.refuse-mschapv2:                    no
ppp.nobsdcomp:                          no
ppp.nodeflate:                          yes
ppp.no-vj-comp:                         no
ppp.require-mppe:                       no
ppp.require-mppe-128:                   no
ppp.mppe-stateful:                      no
ppp.crtscts:                            no
ppp.baud:                               0
ppp.mru:                                1492
ppp.mtu:                                1492
ppp.lcp-echo-failure:                   0
ppp.lcp-echo-interval:                  0
pppoe.service:                          --
pppoe.username:                         <provider_login>
pppoe.password:                         <hidden>
pppoe.password-flags:                   0 (none)
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NOMBRE:                         ppp0
GENERAL.UUID:                           ec723ebc-3675-4d8a-81e8-8989bb275307
GENERAL.DISPOSITIVOS:                   enp1s0
GENERAL.ESTADO:                         activada
GENERAL.PREDETERMINADO:                 sí
GENERAL.PREDETERMINADO6:                no
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.ZONA:                           --
GENERAL.RUTA-DBUS:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.CON-RUTA:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/5
GENERAL.OBJETO SPEC:                    --
GENERAL.MASTER-RUTA:                    --
IP4.DIRECCIÓN[1]:                       <net.wor.k.ip>/32
IP4.PUERTA DE ENLACE:                   80.58.67.182
IP4.DNS[1]:                             80.58.61.250
IP4.DNS[2]:                             80.58.61.254
IP6.DIRECCIÓN[1]:                       fe80::beae:c5ff:fe34:f062/64
IP6.PUERTA DE ENLACE:                   --
```

You might find the Configuration File in:

```
# pwd
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
# ls -lah
total 8,0K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   17 mar 22 14:26 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root root 4,0K feb  7 14:26 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  366 mar 22 14:26 ppp0

# cat ppp0
[connection]
id=ppp0
uuid=ec723ebc-3675-4d8a-81e8-8989bb275307
interface-name=enp1s0
type=pppoe
permissions=
timestamp=1437654424
secondaries=
autoconnect-priority=100
[pppoe]
username=<provider_login>
password=<login_password>    
[ipv6]
method=auto
dns-search=    
[ipv4]
method=auto
dns-search=    
[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=    
[ppp]
nodeflate=true
mru=1492
mtu=1492
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, I was using nmcli somehow did not get around to "con show ppp0" which likely would have gave me more visibility to the ipv6 configuration missing.

Comment: Actually those 4 commands helped me to analyse different network problems and so It can you give insight about what is different at the _bad_ internet connection in comparison with the _good_ one.

Comment: I answered my own question prior to you posting this answer, and the only difference I could see was that IPv6 was not enabled on the "bad" connection. There was no documentation stating it needed to be, but when I went back and looked at the syslog, it indeed had "ipv6" in the pppd options string...